# Configure scheduled MySQL dumps without scripting?

Tags: mysql

Is there an easy way to configure scheduled mysql dumps without scripting?

My setup is Windows Server with MySQL 5.6

Answer (score 0):

I've never done it since I rarely use windows in development.
But maybe you can use this one. This one is windows based.
http://sourceforge.net/projects/mysqlbutool/